# JQuery UI Tooltip on span with disabled child link

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui

I'm working on a project that frequently requires the use of tooltips on disabled links. The project includes a draft/publish system, so I like to inform the user why a certain action is not available through the use of a tooltip.

The way I've been adding these tooltips is by wrapping the link in a `<span>` and adding the tooltip to the `<span>` instead of the link itself.

```
<span class="tooltip-class" title="Reason this link is disabled.">
     <a disabled>Action Name</a>
</span>
```

Up until now this seemed to do the trick. Recently, this method no longer works. Hovering over the `<span>` does not open the tooltip.

I am using chrome, but have experienced the same result in firefox as well.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mwo0x7n5/2)

Any ideas why this stopped working? Suggestions for a workaround or a better solution to my problem are also welcome! Thanks!

Comment: I see the `This link is disabled` text hovering the word Test in the fiddle with both Firefox (69.0.3) and Chrome (77.0.3865.120). So it works for me... am I missing something?

Comment: @PaulT. Interesting. I'm using the same builds. It shows the default `title` attribute text popup. But it's not the jQuery UI tooltip. If you remove the `disabled` attribute from the link and re-run the example it should display differently.

Comment: I've added screen shots of both ways on Firefox [here](https://imgbox.com/gallery/edit/sSIjbHCjPu/VKE7NTttca1XJITd).  (with and without the disabled attribute)

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks for sharing those. Those are the same results I get. The first image, where the disabled attribute is present, is not using jQuery UI's tooltip. It's just displaying the browser's default hover text for elements with a title set. I need the jQuery UI tooltip to display as I have custom css and js for these tooltips in my project.

Comment: Do you plan on removing the href attribute when the link is disabled? `<a>` tags are not disabled if a `href` property is present, the event will still fire. [see this](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/) Anyway, moving the title to the span tag makes the tooltip display as expected, even with having disabled as an `<a>` tag property, if this could be a possible work-around.